# Execute python script on remote server from another script

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys
import commands


os.system('cat disk_space.py | ssh niraj@abc python - "sys.argv[1]"')
```

O/P:

```
python: No match.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe you could try explaining what you're actualy trying to do and bother writing a proper question ?

Answer (score 0):

Directly run python script in your server, listen some one port which is not be used. when the port receive a signal, run the script which you want execute.
How to create socket service:

```
def tcplink(sock, addr):
    print('Accept new connection from %s:%s...' % addr)
    sock.send(b'Welcome!')
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        time.sleep(1)
        if not data or data.decode('utf-8') == 'exit':
            break
        # execute what you want
    sock.close()
    print('Connection from %s:%s closed.' % addr)
```

Keep service alive in your server.